# Flutter - navigation from within a widget build without user input

Tags: flutter, navigation, authorization

I currently have a home page that redirects to either a login page or a front page dependent upon the users authorisation status changing (logged in or not?):

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final value = context.watch<AppState>().authStatus;
    print('Authentication status value: $value');

    return  switch  (value) {
    // (1) Application initialising...
      AuthStatus.uninitialised => const Scaffold(
        body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
      ),
    // (2) User authenticated...
      AuthStatus.authenticated => const FrontPage(),
    // (3) No authenticated user...
      _ => const LoginPage()
    };
  }
}
```

I would prefer to do it the following way using a centralised route generator but cannot figure out how to do it:

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final value = context.watch<AppState>().authStatus;
    print('Authentication status value: $value');

    return  switch  (value) {
    // (1) Application initialising...
      AuthStatus.uninitialised => const Scaffold(
        body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
      ),
    // (2) User authenticated...
      AuthStatus.authenticated => *Navigator.replace(context, Routes.generateRoute('/front'));*
    // (3) No authenticated user...
      _ => *Navigator.replace(context, Routes.generateRoute('/login'));*
    };
  }

}
```

Obviously this will not build because of the *Navigator.replace()* calls not reurning a widget. Is there a simple way of doing this kind of redirection?